# Symfony 2 & Doctrine 2 - create a custom findBy() method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like create my own method `findBy()`.
I have two entities: `Film` and `Genre`. The purpose of this custom `findBy()` method is :

- join the `Film` entity with the `Genre` entity, to retrieve all my films
  and the associated genres,
- keeping the parameters of the basic method which are: `$criteria`,
  `$orderBy` , `$limit` and `$offset`.

Indeed, I use those parameters to make a paging.

Previously I made a custom findAll method with the join between the two entities :

```
<?php
public function myFindAll()
{
    $films = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        // leftJoin because I need all the genre
        ->leftJoin('f.genres', 'g')
        ->addSelect('g.label')
        ->groupBy('f.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    // $genres contains all the genres and the associated movies
    return ($films);
}
```

I don't know how to include the rest of parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your question, do you want to have something like `myFindBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset)` and use these parameters when dealing with `createQueryBuilder()`?

Comment: Yeah i want something like myFindBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset). I want to keep all the parameters but the query has to include the joint I put above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about slice() ?

```
$genders = $em->getRepository('models\Gender')->findAll()->slice($offset, $lenght);
```

Also, you can make use of your function like:

```
public function myFindAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset)
{
    $films = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        // leftJoin because I need all the genre
        ->leftJoin('f.genres', 'g')
        ->addSelect('g.label')
        ->groupBy('f.id')
        ->add('orderBy', "f.{$orderBy} ASC")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult()
        ->slice($offset, $limit);

    // $films contains all the genres and the associated movies
    return ($films);
}
```

**EDIT:**

The `slice()` function acts as pagination function:

```
$page1 = $films->slice(0, 15); // retrieve films from 0 to 15 position
$page2 = $films->slice(10, 7); // retrieve films from 10 to 17 position
```

Now, if you want to use some criterias values you can make something like this:

```
public function myFindAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset)
{
    $films = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');

    foreach($criteria as $column => $value)
        $films->where($column, $value);

    $films
        ->leftJoin('f.genres', 'g')
        ->addSelect('g.label')
        ->groupBy('f.id')
        ->add('orderBy', "{$orderBy[0]} {$orderBy[1]}");
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult()
        ->slice($offset, $limit);

    // $genres contains all the genres and the associated movies
    return ($films);
}
```

I am not sure if `where` function will override the previous conditions, but at least it can lead you to find the correct query

### setFirstResult() and setMaxResult()

Also, there is another option  that you can use:

```
public function myFindAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset)
{
    $films = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');

    foreach($criteria as $column => $value)
        $films->where($column, $value);

    $films
        ->leftJoin('f.genres', 'g')
        ->addSelect('g.label')
        ->groupBy('f.id')
        ->add('orderBy', "f.{$orderBy[0]} {$orderBy[1]}")
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    // $genres contains all the genres and the associated movies
    return ($films);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this line seems to get all genders. In my context I would like all movis with associated genders

Comment: First... thx a lot for your response because its works perfectly ! But can you just explain what doest the method "slice()" do ?  

Then $criteria is an array which permit you to make a filter on your query. For example if I only want the movies of Christopher Nolan if will add a parameter :

$films_list = $repository->myFindAll(
            array('director' => 'Christopher Nolan'),                 
            array('id' => 'desc'),   
            $limit,           
            $offset                  
        );

Comment: Hi, I have this error : Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ../../FilmRepository.php line 26 which is :
->add('orderBy', "{$orderBy[0]} {$orderBy[1]}").

The $orderBy contains an array : array('id' => 'desc')

Comment: I try another way to include the orderBy like you did for the $criteria :  `foreach($orderBy as $column => $value)
         $films->orderBy($column, $value);`
And now I have this error : `Call to a member function slice() on a non-object`

Comment: What is your Doctrine version?

Comment: Look the file Doctrine.php, into it there is var name Version, because slice function is only for +2.1 ... [slide function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\Videotheque\src\gstyle39\VideothequeBundle\Repository\FilmRepository.php line 31 whichs is : `->add('orderBy', "{$orderBy[0]} {$orderBy[1]}")`. I think the variables are not read correctly

Comment: for the "setFirstResult" method, I think it should be (notice the "f."):
`->add('orderBy', "f.{$orderBy[0]} {$orderBy[1]}")`

This should fix Adrien G's issue too. Remember, in plain text that should be:
`->add('orderBy', "f.column_name ASC")`

Comment: i have this error Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::slice()

Comment: @Barno, that's because you are using a old version of doctrine.